# Google forms script to save responses into a csv (not excel) by default and email it as attachment

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a google form which appends responses to an Excel format file. I have also attached a script to it which parses the response and emails the results...

Building on that, how would I do the following additional steps:

1. Keep the current behavior which appends responses to the default EXCEL spreadsheet format file.
2. Convert the default EXCEL spreadsheet format file to a file called allresonses.txt (CSV format)
3. Saves the current responses as mytest.txt (CSV format) and have this emailed as an attachment. (Currently I am able to only add them to an email using my script)

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Excel(`.xslx`) or simply spreadsheet (Google Sheets) in the format of the responses output you mentioned? Also, take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685975/google-forms-onsubmit

Comment: Hi Jonathan ..Thank you kindly for the reply .. I am actually trying to have the response(s) saved as CSV and then mailed as a CSV attachment.see original post for clarity ..Hope that helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use scripts , I check the google forms script examples.
Quick walk through:
1. Just create a form in google forms and add your questions.
2. Create a script on the add script page (of course google for the correct script or check the developer forum examples)
3. While the default is a spreadsheet format you can select one of the supported types (again I check the google developer examples,they're somewhat dated but do still work.)

All sorted now.

Thank you