# Google Apps - on Form Submit - what is the name of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

The following code from Alex's code on [Google Forms onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685975/google-forms-onsubmit)
will send an email when a form attached to the spreadsheet is submitted.

```
function onSpreadsheetSubmit(e) {
     var row = e.range.getRow();
     MailApp.sendEmail("me@example.com",
                "Your subject, rows: "+ row,
                "A new application has been submitted on row: "+
                row,
                {name:"From your friendly spreadsheet"});
}
```

The code successfully returns the row number of the submission using `e.range.getRow()`

How can I get the name of the sheet that the form is connected to?
E.g. something like `e.range.getSheet()`

Although this question [How to get form values in the submit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429161) discusses retrieving the event values, I do not believe that it addresses directly the retrieval of the name of the sheet.

And how can I elegantly get the data of the new row?

Comment: Are you pasting this code into the form or into the spreadsheet?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429161

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get form values in the submit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429161/how-to-get-form-values-in-the-submit-event-handler)

Comment: The code is pasted into the google apps script associated with the spreadsheet. The links are very interesting and useful, but I feel that my precise question was only answered here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is return the sheet name from your event object, use:

```
var name = e.range.getSheet().getName();
```

To access the values submitted to the form, you can use:

```
var values = e.values;
```

This returns the submitted values in an array.

There are a lot of possibilities with event objects, you should really look into the documentation to find out how to use them to your advantage.

---

#### References:

1. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) documentation.